# How do I call multiple python functions by reference to operate on a variable so that I can change the sequence of function calls easily?

Tags: python, function, sequence, pass-by-reference, call

I want to create a 'function pipeline', like a factory.

Let's say I have the following functions:

```py
def func1(var):
    var = # do something with var
    return var

def func2(var):
    var = # do something else with var
    return var

def func3(var):
    var = # do another thing with var
    return var

def func4(var):
    var = # do something with var we haven't done before
    return var
```

Now I want to call all functions on my object in sequence, but I want to test calling them in all possible sequence permutations and check the results because the final result will vary based upon the sequence in which the functions were called.

How do I change this manual sequence of function calls:

```py
myvar = something
myvar = func1(myvar)
myvar = func2(myvar)
myvar = func3(myvar)
myvar = func4(myvar) # final variable function transformation (result)
```

... into something that I can iterate through all possible sequences of, but without having to manually code it as follows?

```py
def func1(var):
    var = # do something with var
    return var

def func2(var):
    var = # do something else with var
    return var

def func3(var):
    var = # do another thing with var
    return var

def func4(var):
    var = # do something with var we haven't done before
    return var

myvar = func4(func3(func2(func1(myvar))))
# or
myvar = func3(func4(func2(func1(myvar))))
# or
myvar = func3(func2(func4(func1(myvar))))
# or
myvar = func3(func2(func1(func4(myvar))))
# or
myvar = func4(func2(func3(func1(myvar))))
# or
# ...etc...
# or (finally)
myvar = func1(func2(func3(func4(myvar))))
```

Comment: AFAICT, every example given in that post you linked to  permutates variables, not function calls. I want to call functions in all sequence permutations. I guess I need to get the references in for all functions then add those to a list and permute that?

Comment: @skeetastax There's no difference between permuting variables and functions. Just call the elements of the permutation in a loop.

Comment: `myvar = f1(f2(f3(f4(myvar))))`

Comment: yeah...just watching something on python function decorators....starting to see that now.

Comment: Functions are objects like any other, and you can easily assign them to a variable or a list.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out:

```py
import itertools

def func1_square(var):
    var = var ** 2
    return var

def func2_triple(var):
    var = var * 3
    return var

def func3_quarter(var):
    var = var / 4
    return var

def func4_minus1(var):
    var = var - 1
    return var

funcseq = list(itertools.permutations([func1_square, func2_triple, func3_quarter, func4_minus1]))

#print("Number of unique function sequences: {}".format(len(funcseq)))

def callfuncseq(seq, this):
    f = 1
    for func in seq:
#        print("F: {}; function: {}".format(f, func))
        this = func(this)
        f = f + 1
    print("RESULT: {}".format(this))
    return this

def main(n):
    results = []
    s = 1
    for seq in funcseq:
        print("SEQ: {}".format(s))
        results.append(callfuncseq(seq, n))
        s = s + 1
    return results

input = 8
final = main(input)
```

Comment: Based on your code, you might like to use `enumerate`.

Answer (score -1):

To get all functions permutations you can use `itertools.permutations`

Also to apply a sequence of functions to a value you can use `functools.reduce`

```
import functools
import itertools

def applyfunc(val, func):
    return func(val)

def apply_sequence(sequence, val):
    return functools.reduce(applyfunc, sequence, val)

def apply_permutations(func_list, val):
    return map(apply_sequence,
               itertools.permutations(sequence))


# use it like this:

for v in apply_permutations([f1, f2, f3, f4], val):
    print v
```

Comment: `import reduce` fails. 'pip install reduce` also fails. Where is this module located?

Comment: Reduce is in [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: I don't see how defining a function that uses reduce is any better than `ans = f1(f2(f3(f4(x))))` as similarly suggested by @Barmar

Comment: sorry I should import itertools not reduce. I am horrecting it

Comment: the use of reduce make the function more general, which can be applied to an arbitrary list of functions.

Comment: This crashes, for at least three reasons.